# Not able to use google closure with syntastic in vim

Tags: vim, syntastic

I have included the following lines in my vimrc file to run syntastic plugin.[closed]

```
let g:syntastic_mode_map = { 'mode': 'active',
                           \ 'active_filetypes': [],
                           \ 'passive_filetypes': ['html'] }

" To enable this plugin, edit the .vimrc like this:
let g:syntastic_javascript_checker = "closurecompiler" 
" and set the path to the Google Closure Compiler:
   let g:syntastic_javascript_closure_compiler_path = '~/.vim/closure-compier/compiler.jar'

 let g:syntastic_enable_signs=1
 let g:syntastic_auto_loc_list=1
```

But it doesnt seems to work,I tried debuging the closurecompiler.vim script .Inside it function SyntaxCheckers_javascript_GetLocList() has the makeprg variable when i echo the variable it prints the following line

```
 java -jar ~/.vim/closure/closure.jar --js 'workspace/abc.js'
```

but does not show any error ,however if i enter same line in console i get all errors 
What am i doing wrong in my setup. you can see my setup on [github](https://github.com/devendra98602/myvim)

Comment: What you type in the terminal is different from what you have in your vimrc. Fix that to see if it works better. Also I think that it's "closure-compiler", not "closure-compier".

Comment: I think my `closurecompiler` argument was right and not `closure-compiler` because you can see from image that now its not even able to find right syntax checker.
Also if put the line printed by vim directly in my terminal i get o/p 

`java -jar ~/.vim/closure-compiler/compiler.jar  --js 'Desktop/syntx.js'
Desktop/syntx.js:1: ERROR - Parse error. IE8 (and below) will parse trailing commas in array and object literals incorrectly. If you are targeting newer versions of JS, set the appropriate language_in option.
var obj = { ar  : 'sadada',              
            ^
1 error(s), 0 warning(s)`

Comment: [vim setup](https://github.com/devendra98602/myvim) This is setup is use Is there any thing wrong in it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think i found your mistake. I just downloaded your [setup via github](https://github.com/devendra98602/myvim) and this line had a typo in your .vimrc file:

```
let g:syntastic_javascript_closure_compiler_path = '~/.vim/closure-compier/compiler.jar'
```

When I changed this line to this:

```
let g:syntastic_javascript_closure_compiler_path = '~/.vim/closure-compiler/compiler.jar'
```

And launched gvim abc.js I get this:

[image: ss of vim w/ abc.js and closure]

Seems to be working now.

Comment: Man I am Dumb! Romainl did pointed out this mistake but i was too dumb to understand but thanks anyway for taking out time to answer

Comment: No prob. Now I know how to use syntastic and google's closure lint checker so it was worth it. Thanks for the knowledge! Please accept this answer if you don't mind.

Comment: ya sure, but for awarding bounty stackoverflow has rule that i can award it only after 24 hrs.

Comment: Do you mean that you have to wait 24 hours or that the bounty has to be offered for 24 hours and then someone answers the question?

Comment: @deven98602, told you so ;-)

Comment: yes I will have to wait for 24 hrs before i can award your answer